# Invalid redeclaration of 'viewWillTransition(to:with:)' in swift 3

Tags: swift3, ios10, viewwilltransitiontosize

I'm trying to implement the required methods of viewWillTransition but I'm getting a weird error:

> Invalid redeclaration of 'viewWillTransition(to:with:)'

I've used it in swift 2 without problem But Swift 3 error

my Code :

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator){

        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

        guard let pageIndex = imageScrollView.auk.currentPageIndex else { return }
        let newScrollViewWidth = size.width 

        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { [weak self] _ in
            self?.imageScrollView.auk.scrollToPage(atIndex: pageIndex, pageWidth: newScrollViewWidth, animated: false)
            }, completion: nil)

    }
```

Comment: By mistake you have added `viewWillTransition` method twice in your project remove one will solved the error

Comment: this is redeclaration error, this function may already used in somewhere. Search this method in your Xcode.

Comment: It is your right.thank you

Comment: @NiravD yeah , Sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Invalid redeclaration of `viewWillTransition(to:with:)`

It means by mistake you have added `viewWillTransition` method twice in your Controller remove one of it will solved the error.